# I am trying to solve a equation with two unkown and trying to find the root of both unkown and getting a cant convert expression to float error

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy as sym
import math as math 
sym.init_printing()
s3,s4 = sym.symbols('s3,s4')
f= sym.Eq(15*math.cos(0.7)+30*math.cos(s3)-40-35*math.cos(s4),0)
g= sym.Eq(15*math.sin(0,7)+30*math.sin(s3)-35*math.sin(s4),0)
print(sym.solve([f,g],(s3,s4)))
```

Comment: Are you sure `math.cos(s3)`, for example, on its own, works?

Comment: `math` functions only work with numbers.  `sympy` has its own `sin/cos`.

Comment: I changed the trigonometric expressions, now using sympy's but this time 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'as_coeff_Mul' comes as an error.

Comment: Also note that you are using a comma in `sin(0,7)` where you probably want a decimal point.